# Does quantum field theory forbid spin-2 gravitons from carrying a charge that would make them repel each other increasingly with decreasing distance?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gravity, charge, carrier-particles

Can repulsive gravitons account for why gravity is weak compared to other forces and would they stop singularities from forming?

Comment: How do you define repulsive gravitons? Normal gravitons are spin 2 massless particles necessarily coupling to the energy-momentum tensor. From the C structure involved in spin 2-couplings, the induced force *must* be attractive. To be repulsive, the force must be mediated by a vector particle (a "graviphoton"), but then it comports with different spin rules and high energy behavior. Are you *sure* you  insist on basing your  "theory" on QFT?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Hi!Gravitons have not been discovered yet and in fact one possible interpretation of quantum gravity is that gravity is not even a force but a almost infinite # of spacetime blocks.

Comment: @Cerise Perhaps, but this is not the QFT setting explored by the OP; try convincing him. In any case, this is veering into a crank physics session, and might need to be closed...

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Not crank physics. As Travis comments below Steven Weinberg bothered to show why it was wrong.

Comment: That was my first comment. One does not need Weinberg!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, quantum field theory forbids it.  Being spin 2 means that gravitons transform as a tensor of degree 2, and therefore they must couple to a conserved current that is a tensor of degree 2.  The only conserved tensor of degree 2 is the energy-momentum tensor, so there is no other possible charge which could cause repulsion (for a reference, see Section 5.9 of Weinberg's Quantum Theory of Fields Part I).